# EasyPHP index file name change

Tags: indexing, localhost, easyphp

When I use `localhost/website` it opens the file named `index.html`, if the file doesn't exist it opens the target folder.
I have a page called `home.php` which I want it to get used as the index file when I go to `localhost/website`.
How can this be done?

Comment: What kind of web server are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a plain text file called `.htaccess` with the following line of code:

`DirectoryIndex home.php`

and save it in the `localhost\website` folder.

If you already have a `.htaccess` file, just add the above code to it.